# Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and TensorFlow Confusion Matrix with VERY BAD score

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I followed the steps EXACTLY in the Hands on Machine Learning with Scikit Learn and TensorFlow ch. 3. But the confusion matrix for the multinomial classifier is very very bad. Even though the book expects the matrix score to be very good.

The matrix looks like this: 
[image: Confusion Matrix Plot]

But the matrix should ACTUALLY look like this:

[image: Actual Confusion Matrix Plot]

Here is the link to the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x1vhgajdDYovFop59MoT5asQ9qyyP1ka

My question is, what mistake did I make in my steps? And should I adapt my program to future updates in scikit-learn, numpy, and pandas? (The book is stated as outdated in some parts)